# Nginx X-Frame-Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, centos

i use nginx 1.8.0 under centOS 6.7 which serving Ruby On Rails 4.2.3 application.

**The Problem:**

I need to enable iframe options for all domains so tried this:

```
X-Frame-Options: *
```

then when i check headers i see it twice 1 time with `SAMEORIGIN` and one time with `*`, here is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sun, 01 Nov 2015 15:48:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
ETag: W/"d14b3de05fb18ebe4a94774c8f209e7f"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: guess_locale=en; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: _admin_numgames_com_session=Y3N0QjR2NXY0VFlZMlVnMHJLZC9WbUVraldZYjhpeHo0UG41akpaZE1rb0tQWS9YeGpkcklTRmViUU5aVmJpUElCcWpMaFJWQmpIWHRSazI4TE9QdTgvQ2VVRGYrSW9VcjA4eWVCMVlsUHJRejR1WmNoQWZoL2hGeVA1ZHp5YWxPdFZ4S25ydEtTamVnbFlZMEhJRDdXalQ2MU93T24vWnR6b28wM0NvYS82Nm1XMGV2Njh4djIzR1RNb2w3WTVHUDM3cVl3NnVrQnJ1WTMyU3I4dVBjY3RORWRQSlk2VmhNVnRVelZRbHRVWT0tLU9DYVBIZUxoUXlLN2VmZ01VNEhab3c9PQ%3D%3D--fa2a9d6817b5464b82a2babd784ed098f2526eeb; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: 4762503a-a9a8-41ce-b1a7-26269b7e9184
X-Runtime: 0.963198
X-Frame-Options: *
```

there is only 1 time declare this option so why i see it twice? and how do i remove this option so any one will be able to use my domain with iFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i found the solution and Rails was the problem he sent the header, just needed to add into production.rb file:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
}
```